# PHP non-structured file parser

Tags: php, parsing

I'm currently working on a tool to help mod a game, and it uses an unstructured file format, which I am unable to find a decent way to parse.

The example of 1 object of a file, which needs parsing:

```
object = {
    id = id_1
    image = IMG_image_1
    require = { 
        id = id_2
    }
    priority = 1
    value = 2
    time = 10
    locked = yes
    output = {
        EVENT = {
            OUTPUT = { 
                USER = { 
                    reward = custom_reward
                }
                reward = all_players_reward
                bonus_reward = {
                    type = money
                    amount = 100
                    instant = yes
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problems are:

- The items in the object (id, image, etc.) don't need to be in the order displayed, for example, `value = 2` could be the first on the list - and some objects may not use all the items (e.g. locked is not always there).
- The multi-layer objects (output, EVENT, OUTPUT, USER) do not have a strict limit, there could be 10 layers, there could just be 2.

Does anyone know of any PHP functions, libraries, etc. which would be able to parse something like this?

Comment: regex, string functions, array functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is not unstructured - actually it *looks* to have quite a strict structure, but we don't know what that structure is. Certainly it is not XML, JSON, YAML or PHP serialization.

> Does anyone know of any PHP functions, libraries, etc

No - and asking that question here makes your post off-topic.

Since you're looking for something to read this in PHP, you presumably have some programming skills. Key questions to ask before you attempt this are:

1) do the examples you have access to cover every possible feature of the grammar? (in your example above there are no arrays, no dates which often appear in such grammars with specific semantics)

2) are there explicit schema requirements which you need to validate (e.g. must every object have an 'img' property).

Then try to decompose the grammar into a standard form (it looks [BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) is more than adequate for the task here). From there, implementing a parser should be easy.

Comment: Never heard of BNF, but that helps make sense of what I'm trying to do. Thanks :)